# Is a valid answer to a problem a valid answer to a different question?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, accepted-answer

I'm not exactly sure how to formulate my problem, so I'll present it with the help of an [example](https://superuser.com/a/1266556/711025) (which is the actual reason I ask this question). I asked a question (*Delay audio for specific device*) in which I explained what I'm trying to do (Playing sound synchronizedly on multiple devices). Now I got an answer, which actually solves my problem, but doesn't answer the question - that means, I can now play sound synchronizedly, but I still don't know, how to delay audio for a specific device. Before I received this answer, I put a bounty on the question, but I'm not sure, wether the answer should be marked as an answer and therefore receive the bounty, as it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

It is your decision whether or not to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers):

> Decide if the answer is helpful, and then...
>
> - Vote on it (if you have earned the appropriate voting privilege). Vote up answers that are helpful and well-researched, and vote down
>     answers that are not. Other users will also vote on answers to your
>     question.
> - Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your
>     problem.

Note that your bounty still has 4 days to run. You may get additional (better) answers) ...

If you feel the answer doesn't answer your question you can downvote it, which may prevent an automatic bounty award.

See the [bounty rules](https://superuser.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible
>   answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer
>   is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is
>   awarded to anyone.